# Tango With Django - Django1.7

Tags: django-1.7

I've searched the forum and I haven't found the answer to this question.
I'm frustrated because my code seems to match the tutorial exactly and yet it still doesn't work.

I am on Tango With Django section 4.5 and I am trying to set up the urls.

Here is the urls.py file in my project folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'tango_with_django.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
)
```

urls.py from 'rango' app folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

When I run manage.py runserver, the error I get in browser is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in tango_with_django.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^rango/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite normal to have this problem. You need to manually navigate to `http://localhost:8000/rango`

```
url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
```

What this line is doing is that it tells your application if the url has rango/ in it, go to rango.urls to figure out what to do next!!!

The url you're looking at just now is `http://localhost:8000/` and as you can see it hasn't been defined in your url resolver. If you want your app to do something with the root url `http://localhost:8000/` then you need to add a line in your urls.py like this

```
url(r'^$', #do what you want here),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry I took so long to get back to this. Thanks for answering my question! This is very helpful.